# git hub process seems to be running in this repository after deleting index.lock

Tags: node.js, github

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.

After deleting index.lock file

[image]

Comment: That looks fine... the `.git` directory is the directory that git uses to keep track of everything. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The first test would be a simple reboot, to check if the issue persists.

If you cannot reboot right away, check a tool like [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), which allows you to search for any process keeping an handle to your repository folder '`rmc_backend`'(or any file within that folder)